# package system not found in case I wrote system.out.println();

Tags: java

I am writing a simple program:

```java
class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        system.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

on compilation it gives an `error: package system not found`.
Why it do so that package not found instead system is a misspelled class name.

Comment: How will the compiler know that `system` is supposed to be a class rather than a package? Without an import, you could very well be asking for the `out` class in the `system` package.

Comment: that's why i'm askking how it knows it was a package????
why it says system package not found???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why it do so that package not found instead system is a misspelled class name

When you say `something.somethingElse` the compiler assumes you are doing a `packageName.classname`. In this case you were intending to access `out` of the `System` class, but you could very well be trying to access a package called `system` that is not present (in the classpath for instance). So it is a guess from a compiler.

And (I guess) it is so because this is the *better* guess. Let's say the compiler said *class not found*. You might be happy. But tons of others doing `Java.util.List` (instead of `java.util.List`) would complain "I was trying to access the `java.util` package but misspelled it. The compiler wrongly says *Missing class name*.

**Update (for the sake of completeness)**
From @paxdiablo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921594/why-it-says-package-not-found-in-case-i-wrote-system-out-println/6921654#answer-6921602) below:

> The reason why the compiler is assuming it's a package name rather
>   than a class or variable name lies in section 6.5 of the JLS,
>   "Determining the meaning of a name"

Comment: It's not a guess, the JLS is very specific about this sort of stuff, otherwise Java would have all the portability disadvantages of C :-)

Comment: @Mohammad Faisal the link posted is the latest.

Comment: Instead of explaining it. you can correct his error. You need a capital S.

Comment: @Maninder if you read the question (which is now 10 years old) the OP already knew that the name was mis-spelt. They did not know why the compiler said "package not found" instead of "misspelled class name". This answer is an attempt explaining that.

Answer (score 13):

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

You need a capital S

Package names are lower case like java.lang.SomeClass, since it's lowercase it assumes you're looking for a package named system.

Comment: Obviously as there is no system package then how could it find the "system" package.

Comment: @Reuben, that's why it complains, because it DOESN'T find it.

Answer (score 3):

It's `System` with a capital `S`:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Hello");
    }
}
```

The reason why the compiler is assuming it's a package name rather than a class or variable name lies in section `6.5` of the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/download/langspec-3.0.pdf), `"Determining the meaning of a name"`:

> The meaning of a name depends on the context in which it is used. The determination of the meaning of a name requires three steps.
>
> First, context causes a name syntactically to fall into one of six categories: PackageName, TypeName, ExpressionName, MethodName, PackageOrTypeName, or AmbiguousName.
>
> Second, a name that is initially classified by its context as an AmbiguousName or as a PackageOrTypeName is then reclassified to be a PackageName, TypeName, or ExpressionName.
>
> Third, the resulting category then dictates the final determination of the meaning of the name (or a compilation error if the name has no meaning).

Your particular use is an `AmbiguousName`, due to `6.5.1`:

> A name is syntactically classified as a MethodName in these contexts: (1) Before the '(' in a method invocation expression; (2) **some other irrelevant contexts**.
>
> A name is syntactically classified as an AmbiguousName in these contexts: (1) To the left of the '.' in a qualified ExpressionName; (2) To the left of the '.' in a qualified MethodName; (3) **some other irrelevant contexts**.

Based on your code, `system.out.println(whatever)` is a qualified `MethodName` preceded by an `AmbiguousName`. Later on in the process, `6.5.2`, the reclassification, mentioned earlier, takes place:

> If the AmbiguousName is a qualified name, consisting of a name, a '.', and an
>   Identifier, then the name to the left of the '.' is first reclassified, for it is itself
>   an AmbiguousName.
>
> If the name to the left of the '.' is reclassified as a PackageName, then if
>   there is a package whose name is the name to the left of the '.' and that
>   package contains a declaration of a type whose name is the same as the
>   Identifier, then this AmbiguousName is reclassified as a TypeName.
>
> Otherwise, this AmbiguousName is reclassified as a PackageName.
>
> A later step determines whether or not a package of that name actually exists.

Because the reclassification walking up the tree (from `println` towards `system`) never results in a `TypeName`, the default reclassification to `PackageName` is always done.

That's why the error message you see is about a missing package rather than a missing class.

Comment: you don't getting my point.... i'm asking that why the compiler says system package not found????

Comment: @Mohammed, sorry, I did indeed miss the point. I've updated my answer with the reason why the compiler treats this as a package error rather than a class one.

Answer (score 0):

THe only error in this code is that you have written small s instead of capital S in System.out.println("Hello");

Answer (score 0):

The most case in which you get an error `Package system not found in system.out.println("  ");` is because, you have to give your file name as "*nameofpublicclass*.java".
In this example, file name must be "Demo.java".
I think that will solve the error.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler says system package not found...

Because it can't find a package called system ( starting with a lower case s.)

It might be able to find one called System, but that's not what your code asked for.

The compiler almost never guesses.