# Why does it keep giving me a system package error?

Tags: java

I keep getting an error where Java, instead of creating a `.class` file for the file, it gives me the error on command prompt

```
public class TotalAndAverage {
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    final int count = 6;
    double score0 = 98.05;
    double score1 = 100.00;
    double score2 = 80.50;
    double score3 = 62.65;
    double score4 = 77.25;
    double score5 = 90.93;
    double total = score0 + score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5;
    double average = total/count;
    int averageInt = (int)average;
    int average2Digit = (int)(average * 100) - averageInt *100;

    System.out.println("Total Score is: \t" + total);
    System.out.println("Average is \t" + average);
    system.out.println("Average Score is: \t" + averageInt + "." + average2Digit);
}
}
```

It shows

> error: package system does not exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [package system not found in case I wrote system.out.println();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921594/package-system-not-found-in-case-i-wrote-system-out-println)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line should be

```
System.out.println(.....)
```

not `system`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `something.somethingElse` the compiler assumes you are doing a `packageName.classname`

BTW, `system.out.println("Average Score is: \t" + averageInt + "." + average2Digit);` make the `system` part as **S**ystem.